# Testing Elasticsearch with JMeter

Tags: json, elasticsearch, jmeter

I am trying to load test a site that has Elasticsearch included as a feature. I recorded a site workflow ( a bunch of steps ) and downloaded the session as a HAR file, and then proceeded to convert the HAR file as JMX. But it is failing on the search Sample: Which basically does a GET on https://stg-cxsearch.md.com/etp/etp_scorecard_states/_msearch

error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body or source parameter is required"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body or source parameter is required"},"status":400}
```

I recorded this as:

```
https://stg-cxsearch.md.com/etp/etp_scorecard_states/_msearch?source=%7B%7D%0A%7B%22query%22:%7B%22match%22:%7B%22field_state%22:%22US%22%7D%7D%7D%0A&source_content_type=application%2Fjson
```

results in:

```
{"responses":[{"took":3,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":
{"total":1,"max_score":3.6018682,"hits":[{"_index":"etp_scorecard_states","_type":"_doc","_id":"494161","_score":3.6018682,"_source"
:{"nid":494161,"type":"states","title":"US","field_c_completed_percent":0.65,"field_c_cost_per_non_wioa":7875.26,"field_c_cost_per_wioa"
:5132.63,"field_c_credential_earned":570178,"field_c_cred_attainment_percent":0.43,"field_c_median_earnings":9645.99,"field_c_q2_employed"
:704821,"field_c_q2_employment_percent":0.53,"field_c_q2_exits":"","field_c_q4_exits":"","field_c_total_completed":857298,"field_c_total_cost_wioa"
:767559260.15,"field_c_total_enrolled":77,"field_c_total_exited":1324572,"field_c_wioa_completed_percent":0.77,"field_state":"US","field_total_wioa_served_with_ita"
:149545}}]},"status":200}]}
```

I need to understand, what do I use as a request body, to get the correct response

Comment: search response you got is for which url, hope this is not the response of `https://stg-cxsearch.md.com/etp/etp_scorecard_states/_msearch?source=%7B%7D%0A%7B%22query%22:%7B%22match%22:%7B%22field_state%22:%22US%22%7D%7D%7D%0A&source_content_type=application%2Fjson
`

Comment: nops, not exactly, I obfuscated the domain, so md.com is a fake domain to protect the identity of the actual domain used